# CollectionViewCell issue. From .xib to storyboard transition for custom collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uistoryboard

I have a custom TagCollectionViewCell which is a custom UICollectionViewCell. In .xib days I used to instantiate through UINib but now using Storyboard I am clueless.

```css
 UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TagCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
 [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TagCell"];
 
 
 _sizingCell = [[cellNib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

In storyboard I pasted the nib in the .storyboard, gave it the assigned custom class. But I am getting a white screen. This is my custom collection cell which I want it in to be the storyboard.
[image: .xib snapshot to be changed into the storyboard.]

What changes should i do in the collection view cell_for_item_atindexpath. The code for .xib was as follows.

```css
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 TagCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TagCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 
 [self _configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
 
 return cell;
}
```

and for configuring the layout was this.

```css
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [self _configureCell:_sizingCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
 
 return [_sizingCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
}
```

Comment: Hi. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom collection view cell with storyboard also.

Make subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

Set DataSource and Delegate.

Set class and Identifier in storyboard as suggested in image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have done that .  Am i missing something in cellForItemAtIndexPath. Will it be different while using storyboard. Consider **"dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier"** , I will provide the identifier used in the storyboard, I did that , anything else I am missing.

Comment: I got it!. I need to typecast it to (TagCollectionViewCell*)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the data source and the delegate for your CollectionView. One of the most common mistake. Tell me if some more help is required.

Comment: Yes, how can I forget that.